# What's the best way to display a small embedded animated image with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flv

I need to display a small (15x15 pixel) animation in a Flex app.  I have it FLV format, but it could be converted to somthing else.  I'd prefer to have the file embedded in the app (it's only 8k in size).  I've seen posts about displaying animated GIFs using third-party code which would be OK, but is there a way to do this with the native Flex libs.  I also realize that FLVs can be displayed in Video objects but only if they are external files.

Comment: Please use the Add Comment link instead of posting answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot easier converting it into a SWF and displaying it in an `Image` control. [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) can convert animated GIF into SWF file, small enough to be embedded in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively you could convert it into a good old animated GIF file and use this package to embed and play it back:

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a blank frame in SWF either in the beginning or the end.